# Многомерный массив и рекурсия в PHP

Tags: php, массивы, рекурсия, foreach

Добрый вечер.

Пробую сделать развернутое меню категорий. Есть многомерный массив, вот часть для примера:

```
Array
(
    [297] => Array
        (
            [categories_id] => 297
            [parent_id] => 0
            [categories_name] => Заготовки для вышивки клатчей
        )

    [51] => Array
        (
            [categories_id] => 51
            [parent_id] => 0
            [categories_name] => Вышивка крестом
            [sub] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [categories_name] => Наборы для вышивки крестом
                            [parent_id] => 51
                            [categories_id] => 2
                            [sub] => Array
                                (
                                    [5] => Array
                                        (
                                            [categories_id] => 5
                                            [parent_id] => 2
                                            [categories_name] => Детские
                                        )

                                    [6] => Array
                                        (
                                            [categories_id] => 6
                                            [parent_id] => 2
                                            [categories_name] => Животные
                                        )

                                    [251] => Array
                                        (
                                            [categories_name] => Закладки
                                            [parent_id] => 2
                                            [categories_id] => 251
                                            [sub] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [253] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [categories_id] => 253
                                                            [parent_id] => 251
                                                            [categories_name] => Без вышивки
                                                        )

                                                    [252] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [categories_id] => 252
                                                            [parent_id] => 251
                                                            [categories_name] => С вышивкой
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [20] => Array
                                        (
                                            [categories_id] => 20
                                            [parent_id] => 2
                                            [categories_name] => Иконы
                                        )

                                    [144] => Array
                                        (
                                            [categories_id] => 144
                                            [parent_id] => 2
                                            [categories_name] => Клатчи
                                        )
```

Пробую написать рекурсию для него:

```
function show_menu($arr) {
    $c_str = '';
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        $c_str .='<li>'.$val['categories_name'];
        if(is_array($val)) {
            $c_str .='<ul>';
            show_menu($val);
            $c_str .='</ul>';
        }
        $c_str .='</li>';
    }
    return $c_str;
}
```

В итоге получаю вывод только первого уровня вложенности. Прошу натолкнуть на мысль, указать на ошибку.

Comment: В строке `$c_str .='<li>'.$val['categories_name'];` вы обращаетесь к массиву и только потом в строке `if(is_array($val)) {` проверяете, массив ли это. Интересно.

Comment: @nictboom, если Вы получили ответ на свой вопрос, пожалуйста, отметьте его верным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$val` - у вас и так массив, наверное вы хотите проверить `$val['sub]`:

```
if(isset($val['sub']) && is_array($val['sub'])) {
```

ну результат рекурсии куда то стоит добавить, что бы его сохранить и вернуть:

```
$c_str .= show_menu($val);
```

Comment: Да, мое упущение про сохранение рекурсии. Вроде все отобразилось. Спасибо за помощь..

Comment: Здесь спасибо говорят отмечая ответ верным) Пожалуйста.

Comment: Простите, буду знать.)